# Maven javadoc plugin won't use my stylesheet

Tags: css, maven

I'm trying to run the javadoc:javadoc goal for Maven for my Java 1.7 project. I'd like to specify my customized stylesheet in /src/main/java/stylesheet.css to use when running the goal, but the default javadoc stylesheet is used instead.

I've tried adding the following to my pom.xml file, as the https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/stylesheet-configuration.html documentation on the Apache Maven site suggests:

```
 <reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <stylesheetfile>src/main/java/stylesheet.css</stylesheetfile>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </reporting>
```

But this doesn't get the desired result when I run the maven javadoc:javadoc goal. Any suggestions?

Update: I've tried with

```
      <configuration>
        <stylesheetfile>theme-irvine.css</stylesheetfile>
      </configuration>
```

And with

```
      <configuration>
        <stylesheetfile>${basedir}/src/main/java/theme-irvine.css</stylesheetfile>
      </configuration>
```

in my pom.xml file, and neither of those worked, either.

Comment: Just try with `<stylesheetfile>stylesheet.css</stylesheetfile>`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I just tried it, but that didn't work.